# Direct sum of two subspaces is $R^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let be U=[(1,-4,2,-3), (-3,8,-4,6)]. Find a subspace W of $R^4$ so, that $U \oplus W = R^4$ 
I really would need help. I do not really know/understand what I should do or how can I do it.

Comment: Find a basis for $U$ (you already know a spanning set for $U$, so check whether it is linearly independent). Extend the basis of $U$ to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$. Then let $W$ be the subspace spanned by those elements you added to the basis.

Comment: So i check if the to vectors given are linearly independent. Then I make U=[(1,-4,2,-3), (-3,8,-4,6), v1, v2] in which I find v1, v2 who are also lineary independent and then I set W=[v1, v2]? Is this right? Could you also please give me a simple explanation as to why this is so.

Comment: You want to find $v_1,v_2$ such that $[(1,-4,2,-3),(-3,8,-4,6),v_1,v_2]=\mathbb{R}^4$, then set $W=[v_1,v_2]$. The reason is that $U\oplus W=\mathbb{R}^4$ is the same as saying that stiching a basis of $U$ and a basis of $W$ together yields a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$ (the spanning property encodes that every vector in $\mathbb{R}^4$ can be written as $u+w$ with $u\in U$ and $w\in W$ and the linear independence encodes that $U\cap W=\{0\}$, i.e. this representation is unique).

Comment: Okay I kinda understand it now. Thank you very much. I only have one question left, the square brackets used while defining U, what do they exactly mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u=(1,-4,2,-3),v=(-3,8,-4,6)$. Note that $w=-2u-v=(1,0,0,0)$, so the two vectors are clearly linearly independent and hence a basis for $U$. $r=(0,0,1,0)$ and $s=(0,0,0,1)$ are linearly independent and not in $U$. So we can take $W$ to be the subspace spanned by them.

To establish the $U\oplus W=\mathbb{R}^4$ we need to show that (1) $U+V=\mathbb{R}^4$, and (2) $U\cap W=0$.

(1) We have $$(a,b,c,d)=\left(\Big(a+\frac{b}{4}\Big)w-\frac{b}{4}u\right)+\left(\Big(c+\frac{b}{2}\Big)r+\Big(d-\frac{3b}{4}\Big)s\right)\in U+W$$ which establishes (1).

(2) If a non-zero vector belongs to $U\cap V$, then we can write it as $aw+bu$ and also as $-cr-ds$. So we have $aw+bu+cr+ds=0$, and hence $(a+b,-4a,2a+c,-3a+d)=(0,0,0,0)$. The second component is 0, so $a=0$. Then the first, third and fourth components are 0, so $b=c=d=0$. Hence $U\cap W=0$.

If you are happy to use a little more theory, then either (1) or (2) is sufficient on its own. Because $\mathbb{R}^4$ has dimension 4, so if (1) is true, 4 vectors spanning it must be linearly independent. Conversely, if (2) is true, then the four linearly independent vectors must span the space.

Comment: excellent explanation. only two small things remain unclear to me, how excactly can i get w and why that step important and how exactly did you get the (a,b,c,d) equation. Thank you very much, really.

Comment: (A) many different $W$ are possible. With the two vectors I chose, $W$ is all the vectors $(0,0,c,d)$ (for any reals $c,d$). (B) By choosing a suitable multiiple of $w$ I can get any first component I want without affecting any of the other components. Similarly, for $r$ and the third component, and $s$ and the fourth component. So I pick the multiple of $u$ first as $-b/4$. That gives $b$ as the second component. It also affects the other three components, but it is easy now to choose the multiples of $u,r,s$ to correct them.

Comment: Thank you very much